# DevExpress Xtrareport Direct Print without preview

Tags: printing, devexpress, xtrareport

I create a Receipt Report by Xtrareport it work properly, what I need is:
vb.net code to print the report directly when pressing the Print Button without showing the preview report.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ReportPrintTool class](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.ReportPrintTool#) to create an instance of a report and immediately send it to a printer.

The [Print a Report](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/5191/winforms-reporting/winforms-reporting-print-api/print-a-report) documentation offers sample code showing how to directly print a report using the ReportPrintTool.Print method. For instance:

```
    Dim report As New XtraReport1()
    Dim printTool As New ReportPrintTool(report))
    ' Invoke the Print dialog.
    printTool.PrintDialog()
    ' Send the report to the default printer.
    printTool.Print()
```